# Slick slider working after some second after reloding page

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

This is my code please check - it's working after some time after reloading the page please help me on this

I am trying to get slick slider when I reload page, but it's only working after some time

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.template-blog .mobile-tag-slider').slick({
          dots: false,
          infinite: true,
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 4,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          centerMode: true, 
          centerPadding: '90px',
          mobileFirst: true, 
          responsive: [
            {
              breakpoint: 600,
              settings: "unslick" 
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 769,
              settings: {
                arrows: false,
                slidesToShow: 4,
                slidesToScroll: 1
              }
            }
          ]
     });
   });
```

it's showing some second like this after reloading page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01bkN.png)

then it's showing right after some second like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1NFV.png)

Comment: Pleas add your markup

Comment: @SaeedShamloo please check my edited question

Comment: I mean add your html code

Answer (score 0):

The document ready function executes when the DOM (Document Object Model) is completely loaded in the browser.

Remove this  code ** $(document).ready(function() **

```
$('.template-blog .mobile-tag-slider').slick({
          dots: false,
          infinite: true,
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 4,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          centerMode: true, 
          centerPadding: '90px',
          mobileFirst: true, 
          responsive: [
            {
              breakpoint: 600,
              settings: "unslick" 
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 769,
              settings: {
                arrows: false,
                slidesToShow: 4,
                slidesToScroll: 1
              }
            }
          ]
     });
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution.

Comment: I have already mentioned to remove document  ready code